# Kaggle .csv file submission error

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, kaggle

I am getting submission error in Kaggle `ERROR: Column '' was not expected (Line 1, Column 1)` when I am submitting my final .csv file

Comment: can you please share the head of your csv file?

Comment: @nimrodz I have added the answer which worked for this specific error. But you are right. The head of file could give a clue.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding **index=False** while saving csv like so:

`output.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)`

Answer (score 1):

`df_for_submission.to_csv('submission.csv', index=False)`

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20349417)

Comment: @Busti I'm afraid this is the complete answer to the question. What do you think is the complete answer to this question? If you have one you can post it below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result_df.to_csv('Submission_file_name.csv', index=False , header = 1)
```